# Gnuplot not recognized in TexStudio

Tags: latex, gnuplot, pdflatex, tikz, pgf

I use *TexStudio 2.8.6* with *MikTex 2.9 (full installation)* in a Win-7 machine. So, `gnuplottex` package is available in the machine.

## Problem

Can't get TexStudio to plot a simple graph with `gnuplot + pgfplots` in `latex`.

## Problem description

I'm trying to plot the following with `gnuplot` in TexStudio:

```
1: \documentclass[]{article}
2: \usepackage{tikz}
3: \usepackage{pgfplots}
4: \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
5:      
6: \begin{document}
7:  
8:     \begin{tikzpicture}
9:     \begin{axis}
10:        \addplot gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)};
11:    \end{axis}
12:    \end{tikzpicture}
13: 
14: \end{document}
```

**TexStudio `Messages`:**
Note the `pdflatex` path. I've tried with and without the `-shell-escape` option.

```
 Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "deleteme".tex
 'gnuplot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
 Process exited with error(s)
```

**TexStudio `Log`:**

```
 Line 10: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'deleteme.sin.table' c>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. gnuplot[id=sin]{sin(x)};
 Line 11: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots.
```

## What I want

Help solve this mystery pls!
Googling the issue didn't yield much. `-shell-escape` option was mentioned. Tried it -- didn't work.

Comment: You must have the path of the gnuplot executable in your PATH variable.

Comment: @Christoph what PATH variable? where?

Comment: From the documentation, you might want to try the `\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}` option.

Comment: @andyras Did. No luck there either.

Comment: I mean Windows environment variable `PATH`. The gnuplottex package only calls `gnuplot.exe`, but doesn't know where this is located. That lookup is probably done via the directories listed in `PATH`.

Comment: @Christoph Figured it out. All working fine. I didn't have windows version of `gnuplot` installed! I naturally thought `pgfplots` had the dependencies for `"gnuplot"` figured out! Thanks. After a while, PATH variable made sense, which in the first place confused me. Since you led me on the right path, you could add it as an answer along with the need to install `gnuplot` ([gnuplot 5.1 for windows](http://www.tatsuromatsuoka.com/gnuplot/Eng/winbin/)) -- I could accept it as an answer then.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer yourself with the steps you had to do :)